# Proving that the intersection of two languages is regular or not?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

> Let $B$ and $C$ be two languages on $A = \{a,b\}$:
>
> $B = \{ w \mid w \text{ has the same number of }a\text{ and }b\text{ symbols}\}$
> $C = \{ a^n b^m \mid n,m \ge 0\}$
>
> Describe $B \cap C$ and determine whether $B$ is regular or not using *only* the closure property of regular languages.

I reasoned like this:

$B$ is not regular because a language is regular if there exists a DFA $M$ such that $L = L(M)$. But we know that DFAs cannot count so $B$ is not a regular language.

$$B \cap C = \{a^n b^m \mid n=m \land n,m \ge 0\}$$

which we know is not regular by the *pumping lemma*.

> Is there a different solution using only closure properties to prove that $B$ is not regular?

Comment: What exactly is the question?  Please specify exactly what your question is, and [edit] your question to remove the parts that are not relevant to that specific question.  You don't need to show us all of the parts of the question if you are asking about only one part.

Comment: @greybeard C is regular because there isn't a condition about counting a and b. However, B ∩ C is not regular according to the pumping lemma. Is there another way to prove it using only closure properties?"

Comment: @D.W Sorry, I am a new user and I still learning the rules to write a correct question.

Comment: @greybeard B∪C is regular due to the closing properties of regular languages

Comment: Sorry, my fault: You know $C$ to be regular. Assume $B$ was regular: What results for $B \cap C$?

Comment: B∩C is regular because the closing properties again apply.

Comment: Your argument "DFAs cannot count" is very loose. For instance, the language $\{u \in A^* \mid |u| \text{ is a prime number lesser than $10^{10}$} \}$ is regular.

Comment: I apologise for the inaccuracy in my statement and thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You are part of the way there.

You are expected to use the closure properties to show whether $B \cap C$ is regular depending on whether $B$ and $C$ are regular. You're not doing that. Closure properties are properties such as:

1. If $A$ is regular, then $\bar A$ (= $\Sigma^* - A$) is regular.
2. If $A$ and $B$ are regular, then $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$ are regular.

Your proof will depend on whether $C$ is regular, so you will need to determine that, too.